# Listview adapter not displaying list columns after closing of Dialog

Tags: java, android, listview

Setup

In my app I have a section that creates rows of data to be saved in a database.  Each row is built from a textbox, number box then "set" into a listview for display.  Later on the user can open a "plan" created before and review the data.

I created a listview, a custom layout for the display line and figured out how to add/display each new row.  However, when I perform the open, I create a dialog to display the list for plans, user selects on and the rows should display.  They do not.  I trace through the code and I see the arraylist for the adapter being populated and I call the notifydatasetchanged, but the main listview remains empty.

I am not using a customer adapter class, but just the Simple adapter.

This is the beginning of the Activity.  I am still learning android coding so I tend to use generic names as I learn.

```
public class TrackItEqMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;
public int rowCount = 1;
private static final String eTAG = "Exception";
final Context context = this;

// global variables needed for processing the add gaits display
**private ListView lstGaits;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;**

// *****

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(eTAG, "onCreate Build");

    setTitle(R.string.activityManagePlans);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_it_eq_build);

    Toolbar mySecondaryToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_secondaryToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mySecondaryToolbar);

    setActivityBuildListeners();

    // set the objects needed to handle the dynamic gaits list
    ListView lstGaits = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMyGaits);
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.gaits_detail,
                new String[] { "keyGait", "keyTime" }, new int[] {
                R.id.txtdisplayGait, R.id.txtdisplayTime  });
        lstGaits.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(eTAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

SO when a user taps a new button a set of controls appear allowing to select a gait and enter a time.  They then tap on the set button and in the set onClick, I add the data to the internal array and display the custom layout on the screen.

```
    private Button.OnClickListener onClick_btnSet = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gaits);
        TextView textGait = (TextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
        String gtResult = textGait.getText().toString();

        TextView txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSelected);
        String tmeResult = txtTime.getText().toString();

        buildDisplayLine(true,gtResult,tmeResult);

        txtTime.setText("");
        spinner.requestFocus();

    }
};
```

The function that builds the line and adds to the array is this:

```
   private void buildDisplayLine(boolean isNew, String gait, String time) {

    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("keyGait",gait);                  // put the col data in
    map2.put("keyTime", time);      // put the col data in
    mylist.add(map2);

    if (isNew) {
        ((BaseAdapter) (adapter)).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

All that works although a strange side effect is that the list will not display if the number keypad is visible.  When I clear it off the list appears.

Ifa use wants to look at or change a plan they tap the open button.  IT display a dialog box that shows a list of plans.  Tap on a plan and all the elements should display:

```
    private final ThreadLocal<OnClickListener> onClick_btnOpen = new ThreadLocal<OnClickListener>() {
    @Override
    protected OnClickListener initialValue() {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_it_eq_open_plan);
                dialog.setTitle("Open Exercise Plan...");

                Button diaCancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelOpen);
                diaCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                // get a list of files from the local app plans
                final eqDatabaseService eqDB = new eqDatabaseService(context, 2);

                ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> allPlans = eqDB.getPlanList();

                if (allPlans.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Files to open, Please create one!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                ListView lvPlan = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lvPlans);

                try {

                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, allPlans, R.layout.plans_columns,
                            new String[] { "keyName", "keyENum" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.txtPlanName, R.id.txtNumElements  });

                    lvPlan.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                //********************************************************



                lvPlan.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        TextView txtplan = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPlanName);
                        String planName = txtplan.getText().toString();

                        List<eqSessions_dt> myPlan = eqDB.getCurrentPlan(planName);

                        clearGrid();

                        for (eqSessions_dt row : myPlan) {

                            buildDisplayLine(false, row.get_gait(),Integer.toString(row.get_time()));
                        }


                        ((BaseAdapter)(adapter)).notifyDataSetChanged();

                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        };
    }
};
```

I have played around with this, did look at other similar questions and answers, but didn't see anything that would explain why the notify would not work.  I avoided doing a custom adapter, trying to keep this simple at first.  What am I missing that stops the list from displaying.  I see the arraylist being filled and all related objects are global to the activity.  I'll keep playing around, but I hope otehr eyes see what I miss.

This is the activity xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.newproject.jhull3341.trackiteq.TrackItEqMainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_secondaryToolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#236dc1"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lyFileAction">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New"
            android:id="@+id/btnNew"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Open"
            android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grdEntry">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/label_time"
            android:id="@+id/lblTime"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_gaits"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/label_Gait"
            android:id="@+id/lblGait"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSelected"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:numeric="integer" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Set"
            android:id="@+id/btnSet"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </GridLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMyGaits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grdEntry"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the custom layout for each display row.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdisplayGait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdisplayTime"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRemoveLine"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.39"
        android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_dark"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: It looks like you are re-creating your adapter with an empty list in ```adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, allPlans, R.layout.plans_columns,
                            new String[] { "keyName", "keyENum" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.txtPlanName, R.id.txtNumElements  });
```

On  side note, I am not sure why you are using ThreadLocal here, do you want localized variables?

Comment: Thank you.  I knew another set of eyes would find what I kept overlooking.  Some of this style of coding is still new, even if I've done it a long ti,e.

I'm not certain what you mean on the second part (threadlocal).  I'll read up on it, but the first step was meant to use local variables to the dialog display, the global for the finished display.

To all, my error was I used one adapter object for two different displays and in doing so, wiped out the arraylist.  I changed the name of the local adapter creation (new) and everything worked fine.  Now I just need to better line up columns.

Comment: What I meant by the ThreadLocal comment is that you probably don't want to do ``` private final ThreadLocal<OnClickListener> onClick_btnOpen``` I'm not sure if OnClickListener is thread safe, but you should almost certainly use a Handler if you need it to be. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)